# Is there a way to ignore type incompatibility in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have been looking at using typescript with mongoose for MongoDB. Mostly it has been working great, but with certain types of quesites I get warnings from the typescript compiler.

If I do an or like so:

```
{"$or": [{done: {"$exists": false}}, {done:false}]}
```

I get the following warning:

`Incompatible types in array literal expression: Types of property 'done' of types '{ done: { $exists: bool; }; }' and '{ done: bool; }' are incompatible.`

I understand why, but is there a way to express this so the compiler will accept it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can type-assert any of the elements to `any` to "turn off" type checking:

```
[<any>{done: {"$exists": false}}, {done:false}]
```

Or, if you're initializing a variable, you can do something like this:

```
var n: any[] = [{done: {"$exists": false}}, {done:false}]
```