# Ionic 2 : Progressbar inside Loading Component - InnerHTML sanitize issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I've been trying to add a progress indicator inside a LoadingComponent (to inform the user about data downloading progress during application startup).

Exemple code :

```
this.loading = this.loadingController.create({
    content: "<progressbar [max]="100" [value]="100" [type]="info></progressbar>"
});
this.loading.present();
```

The issue is that Angular 2 sanitizer remove the progressbar tag because (I suppose) the Loading content is injected inside an [innerHTML].

Since the "content" field only accepts a string, I can't bypass Angular 2 sanitizer (with DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml).

The issue occurs both with the base HTML5 progress and the ng2-boostrap progressbar elements.

Does anyone knows a workaround for this ?
Have I missed something ?
Or is it a real issue that should be directly fixed in Ionic ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very near...

*You can type-assert any of the elements to **any** to "turn off" type checking.*

See the code's comment.

Try with following :

```
export class HomePage {
  private _htmlProperty: string = '<progress></progress>';

  constructor(public nav: NavController,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {    
  }

  public htmlProperty() {
       return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._htmlProperty);
  }

   presentLoading() {
    var html = <any> this.htmlProperty(); // this is the magic
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: html 
    });
    loader.present();
  }
}
```

Took help from

[Is there a way to ignore type incompatibility in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737518/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-type-incompatibility-in-typescript)

Comment: Indeed, I totally forgot that I could do that since I didn't think "string" and "safeHTML" types were compatibles.

Your solution works for a basic HTML <progress> but it doesn't seem's to work with an Angular2 component (such as <progressbar> from ng2-bootstrap).

But without a better solution (or a fix by Ionic2 team), I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Sandeep Sharma, how can I change value of progress bar dynamically in this implementation? please help

Answer (score 5):

Just for extend the @Sandeep answer, using loading.data object allows access component content in order to modify the progress dynamically. For example:

```
getProgressBar(percentaje){
 let html: string = '<progress value="'+percentaje+'" max="100"></progress>';
 return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}

presentLoading(){
  let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
  });
  loader.present();

  let counter: number = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    loader.data.content = this.getProgressBar(counter);
    counter++;
    if (counter == 100) {
      loader.dismiss();
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 10);
}
```

Hope it helps.